Unable to join Google cloud and Firebase DB projects due to Domain Restriction Policy
I am trying to join Google Cloud and Firebase projects as an editor. The owner of the projects sent me an invitation to join, but when I attempt to accept the invitation, I encounter the following error:
'''An organization policy restricts that only users from specific domains are allowed. Please contact an organization admin.'''
What I Tried:
Confirmed with the project owner that the invitation was sent to the correct email address.
Retried accepting the invitation multiple times.
Asked the project owner to review the organization's policy settings in Google Cloud.
Searched Firebase and Google Cloud documentation for relevant solutions but could not find a definitive answer
What I Expected:
I expected to successfully accept the invitation and gain access to the projects as an owner.
